# Ethers.js web3 - Convert token value into Eth

Tags: web3js, react, ethers.js

I am using ethersjs on my react webapp to get the number of one ERC-20 token and others informations after a metamask connection.
I would like also to convert that tokens balance `userBalance` into its equivalent in ETH. I am on Avalanche Network, so it needs to be in AVAX, but I think it is going to be the same way.

```
  const web3Modal = new Web3Modal();
  const connection = await web3Modal.connect();
  const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(connection);
  const signer = provider.getSigner();

  const contract = new ethers.Contract(
    SmartContractAddress,
    SmartContract,
    signer
  );

  const userBalance = await contract.balanceOf(
    userInfo.fullWalletAdddres.toString()
  );
```

Thank you !

Comment: You basically need to use some exchange API to get the current price

Comment: But the token is based on this blockchain, so it has an intrasec value equivalent to the base token (Eth, Avax ...) When you swap on something like uniswap, you have : X tokens per ETH

Comment: Uniswap is an exchange. A token does not have value unless someone is willing to pay for it. Furthermore, there has to be some mechanism for trading it - Uniswap is one such mechanism.

Comment: But you create a pool mixing token and ETH or AVAX. So there is a direct relation between them ?